# Grant Local Install Privileges to Role

Tags: windows-10, azure-active-directory

In our old on-premise AD install, we granted members of IT limited administrative privileges through policy to allow for elevation required to install software, etc on user computers.

We've since opted to Azure AD, due to lowered requirements, but find that our IT members are unable to elevate on user computers now. I've tested with global administrator privileges and are able to elevate and install, but I can't find the specific permission to assign.

Is there an existing role for local install privileges or a privilege that I need to assign to a new role?

Answer (score 0):

You may try additional local administrators on Azure AD joined devices. You can select the users that are granted local administrator rights on a device. Users added here are added to the Device Administrators role in Azure AD. Global administrators in Azure AD and device owners are granted local administrator rights by default. Refer: [Managing devices using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/device-management-azure-portal)